# Rsnapshot entire system drive

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I have up and running Rsnapshot with this...

```
# LOCALHOST
backup  /home/          localhost/
backup  /etc/           localhost/
```

But I want to backup my entire SSD(sdb) and not my external USB drive (sda)...

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M   40M  345M  11% /run
/dev/sdb2        30G  8.4G   20G  30% /
tmpfs           1.9G   20K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb4        69G   53M   66G   1% /home
/dev/sdb1       1.9G  4.5M  1.9G   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       7.3T  4.1T  2.9T  59% /media/data
tmpfs           385M     0  385M   0% /run/user/1000
```

How should my rsnapshot.conf #LOCAHOST file look like???

Thanks for your help here...

Comment: I guess you want to add something like `backup  /          localhost/rootfs` but you are afraid that the mountpoints e.g. `/media/data` are synced too?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that is so. My rsnapshot backup goes in the media/data folder. I want to backup everything except the sda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent `rsnapshot` from traversing mount points when e.g. backing up `/`, you can use `one_fs=1` in the *rsnapshot.conf* file.
The `one_fs=1` will add `-x` to `rsync` which causes `rsync` to stay in the filesytem that was passed as source and to not span different filesystems.

A possible `rsnapshot` configuration could be as follows.

```
backup  /           localhost/rootfs one_fs=1
```

Comment: Great! That is the answer that I needed! Thanks.